# issues in installing Rstem package

Tags: r

I was trying to install "sentiment" package, which requires the "Rstem" package. But the installation process failed due to the following error message,

```
install.packages("Rstem")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘Rstem’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)
```

May I know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

First Try to install Rstem by this command:

```
install.packages("Rstem", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
```

Then try to install sentiment.

It worked for ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6):

Download RStem source file from this link:
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/

Then install the package from the downloaded source file to R:

```
install.packages("Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz" , repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Answer (score 1):

The package can be found here:

http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/web/packages/Rstem/

Download it and install from Zip file, if you're using the Windows flavour of R.

Comment: Just unzip it? Or is there any installation file, like exe file, or do the installation process? How about Linux platform? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Clicking on the link above already solves the issue of the OP, Rstem has been kicked off cran. The link points to the omegahat repo, which @manishVerma mentions.