# More issues regarding the installation of Rstem package

Tags: r, nlp

This question is related to [Issues in Installing Rstem Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945775/issues-in-installing-rstem-package), but I think the answer provided in the previous one isn't working for my case.

I've downloaded the source package and the installation isn't working correctly. Any help is welcomed!

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘~/Downloads/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 2.15.3)
Installing package(s) into ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘Rstem’ ...
** libs
*** arch - i386
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rstem’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rstem’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/mbtangotan/Downloads/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Also tried:

```
install.packages("Rstem", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")
```

Got this as output:

```
trying URL 'http://www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 274336 bytes (267 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 267 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘Rstem’ ...
** libs
*** arch - i386
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rstem’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rstem’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/t3/f4r4rwmn7xl80skj6h35ftnh0000gn/T/RtmpWKxXs2/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rstem", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R",  :
  installation of package ‘Rstem’ had non-zero exit status
```

R Version: 2.15.3, x86_64, OSX.

Comment: I do not think the "issues" are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I have just uploaded to CRAN a new package called SnowballC, which implements the same functions as Rstem and uses the same algorithms. Binary packages for Mac OS X and Windows will be available in a few hours/days.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SnowballC/

Answer (score 3):

If `make` is not found it suggests you need to install an XCode appropriate to your unspecified version of "OSX".

If you did have XCode installed this should succeed (at least it did just now with my MacPro running OSX 10.6.8, R 3.0.0 RC,  and XCode 3.2.6 (1761):

```
install.packages("Rstem", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")
```

Whether there might be other problems, I cannot tell. The package was removed from CRAN, so there may be other alligators in the swamp.

Comment: Hi @DWin...can you elaborate on your XCode comment? I'm in the same situation and would appreciate help :)

Comment: In the same situation as who? What version of OSX, what version of XCode?, trying to install what package from source?

Comment: Thanks so much, how about other packages for OS X?