# Package ‘Rstem’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Tags: r, rstudio, data-science, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to install the `Rstem package`, but I am getting the message that there is no version available for the version of `R 3.5.1`. I'm using the `macOs El Captain`.

The error is:

```
> install.packages('Rstem', repos = 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz')
Installing package into ‘/Users/ls_rafael/Library/R/3.5/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rstem’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
```

I already tried the suggested options in this link [issues in installing Rstem package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945775/issues-in-installing-rstem-package) and also downloading the package locally from the official website [Rstem Package](http://www.omegahat.net/Rstem/), but the result is also unsatisfactory.

I'm studying how to do an `sentiment analysis` with `Twitter` data. I would like to know if there is any alternative to this package or if there is any `trick` to install it.

Comment: The package is no longer available on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rstem/index.html

Comment: You may want to check out the `tidytext` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RStem package has been removed from the CRAN repository. You can download using the following command:-

```
install.packages('Rstem', repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
```

Make sure you have RTools installed on your machine. You can download it from this link -

[Building R for Windows](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Answer (score -1):

RStem is now provided by OmegaHat.
Try the command below:

```
install.packages("Rstem", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R", type = "source")
```